# :include and table aliasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm suffering from a variant of [the problem described here](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2357-predictable-table-aliases-in-joins):

> ActiveRecord assigns table aliases for
>   association joins fairly
>   unpredictably.  The first association
>   to a given table keeps the table
>   name. Further joins with associations
>   to that table use aliases including
>   the association names in the path... 
>   but it is common for app developers
>   not to know about [other] joins at
>   coding time.

In my case I'm being bitten by a toxic mix of has_many and :include.  Many tables in my schema have a `state` column, and the has_many wants to specify conditions on that column: `has_many :foo, :conditions => {:state => 1}`.  However, since the state column appears in many tables, I disambiguate by explicitly specifying the table name: `has_many :foo, :conditions => "this_table.state = 1"`.

This has worked fine until now, when for efficiency I want to add an `:include` to preload a fairly deep tree of data.  This causes the table to be aliased inconsistently in different code paths.  My reading of the tickets referenced above is that this problem is not and will not be fixed in Rails 2.x.  However, I don't see any way to apply the suggested workaround (to specify the aliased table name explicitly in the query).  I'm happy to specify the table alias explicitly in the has_many statement, but I don't see any way to do so.  As such, the workaround doesn't appear applicable to this situation (nor, I presume, in many 'named_scope' scenarios).

Is there a viable workaround?

Comment: Thank you for the question and well explaining it. I can't understand how this type of complex problems don't have solution or explanation in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using :include,  with the :joins key you can explicitly write the join and give it your own table alias. You do have to hand-specify the join, but it will make your requirements completely unambiguous. eg:

```
Bar.all(:joins => "INNER JOIN foos AS my_foos ON my_foos.bar_id = bars.id", :conditions =>  "my_foos.state = 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
:conditions => { :this_table => { :state => 1 } }
```

Comment: It's considered good practice to test your answer when guessing.  The first entry in the hash is a column for the table.

[2010-06-02 15:16:42] [DEBUG]   ThisTable Load (0.000000)   Mysql::Error: #42S22Unknown column 'this_table.this_table' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `this_table` WHERE (`this_table`.`this_table` = '--- 
- :state
- 1
')

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any of the fields from the `:include` tables in the query (as :conditions / :order etc) ? If not, and you just need to load records, you can do it with separate query:

```
records = Bar.all(:joins => ..., :conditions => ..., ...)
Bar.send(:preload_associations, records, [:association1, :association2 ... ])
```

`preload_associations` is protected method (see [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924732/rails-add-custom-eager-load/1924944#1924944) in this answer), but using :joins and :include together usually produces huge SQL query, which is far away from managable.

Comment: Thanks, interesting suggestion.  Yes, the conditions include fields from the :include tables.  I guess I could nonetheless build the preload by hand, and perhaps I'll fall back on that.  That obviates a lot of the elegance of has_many and :include, obviously.